# EventToCommand Update CommandParameter

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

My EventToCommand definition contains some sophisticated CommandParameter which I want to be automatically updated (make binding value up-to-date) when event is fired. Is there any way to achieve this behaviour using EventToCommand?

**Update.** I have a CommandParameter binding which is bound to ElementName and has ValueConverter. ValueConverter retrieves mouse position:

```
Mouse.GetPosition(element)
```

So ValueConverter should be updated right before command is executed.

I know PassEventArgsToCommand could solve this problem, but I don't like this solution.

Comment: Perhaps you can post a code sample showing your command XAML and the ViewModel?

Comment: Can you also describe what you mean by "updating" the CommandParameter. Normally this is bound to some value inside your view model, that gets passed to your command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have downloaded MVVM Light source code and introduced UpdateCommandParameterBeforeExecuting which being set to true explicitly updates CommandParameterProperty before command executing.

Here is source code:

```
...
/// <summary>
/// Specifies whether CommandParameter property should be updated before Command execution
/// </summary>
public bool UpdateCommandParameterBeforeExecuting
{
    get; 
    set; 
}
...
protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
{
    ...
    var command = GetCommand();

    if (UpdateCommandParameterBeforeExecuting)
    {
        BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, CommandParameterProperty).UpdateTarget();
    }

    var commandParameter = CommandParameterValue;
    ...
}
...
```